# Linq & SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, linq

Morning all,

I'm aware that LINQ was packaged with SharePoint 2010 but I'm wondering on the feasability of tools such as Linqpad with SharePoint 2007.  I've recently inherited a SharePoint 2007 farm and wondered if there were any tools that introduced LinQ capabilities to the MOSS Platform?

Many thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4734022/1340960) on Stackoverflow regarding Linq and SP 2007.

Quote from the site:

> SharePoint 2007 does not support Linq (.net 3.5) out of the box, i guess you are using a template??
>
> You will need to follow a guide to get it setup:
>
> http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/09/22/how-to-get-up-and-running-with-net-3-5-in-your-sharepoint-environment.aspx
>
> Then maybe this guide will help you build your query
>
> http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/09/24/how-to-use-linq-and-the-net-3-5-framework-with-sharepoint-to-retreive-sharepoint-list-items.aspx

Comment: Cheers for these.  I'll give them a go and will mark up the post as the answer shortly.  Thanks again!